# iframe content not appear

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

I have this code and sometimes works and sometimes not:

```
   var urlThemes2="../usuarios/"+parent.parent.parent.Nb_Global_usuario+"/aplicaciones/"+parent.parent.parent.Nb_Global_aplicacion+"/appfiles/includes/themes/";
    alert("preview")
    $("#listaTemas2").attr("src","Nb_ListaTemas.php?urlThemes="+urlThemes2);
```

In the Chrome's inspector shows the iframe's "src" defined, but not the html content.

Any solution?

Thanks,

Comment: Not the solution, but please add an ; to alert("preview") .

Comment: thanks @BenniKa but it's not relevant..

Comment: What is different about the environment and usage when it sometimes works and sometimes not?

Comment: @MrCode the usage and environment is the same always.

Comment: Any error messages when it doesn't work?

Comment: Hi guys! I fix now it, the problem was in the height of the div, dynamically was changed and I didn't know itHi guys! I fix it, the problem was in the height of the div, dinamically was changed and I didn't know.

Thanks!